Upload files from S3 bucket to Salesforce using AWS Services
We need to automate the upload of various files (PDFs and photos) from an S3 bucket directly into Salesforce Files. While we successfully use AWS AppFlow to import data from a CSV file in S3 to a Salesforce table, we haven't found a similar native AWS service for file uploads.
Our goal is to migrate a large volume of files (approximately 30 million, totaling 2 TB) from S3 to Salesforce Files.
We'd appreciate any suggestions or recommendations on the best approach for achieving this data transfer.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/374465/salesforce-files-for-massive-storage
